# checking the boolean value in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I Have an xml

```
<FIELD>
 <FNAME>isFirstOfTheMonth</FNAME>
 <TYPE>SVR_BOOLEAN</TYPE>
 <VALUE>false</VALUE>
 </FIELD>
 <FIELD>
```

I am trying to check the boolean value. if its not the first of the month then display the text

```
<xsl:if test="not(FIELD[FNAME='isFirstOfTheMonth']/VALUE) =false">
  <fo:block font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="11.0pt" text-align="left">
    <xsl:text>The  liability is &#36;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="FIELD[FNAME='amount]/VALUE" />
    <xsl:text>&#160;effective&#160;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="FIELD[FNAME='StartDate']/VALUE" />
    <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
  </fo:block>
</xsl:if>
```

when the value is false i am not seeing the text in output.

Can anyone help me?
BTW xsl version 1

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> not(FIELD[FNAME='isFirstOfTheMonth']/VALUE) =false
> ```

I think that closing parenthesis is in the wrong place. You are comparing the result of the `not` to `false`, do you want to compare the content of the `VALUE` element to "false"? In which case using not-equals would be better:

```
FIELD[FNAME='isFirstOfTheMonth']/VALUE != 'false'
```

noting that you need to put strings in quotes…. Thus

```
<xsl:if test="FIELD[FNAME='isFirstOfTheMonth']/VALUE != 'false'">
  …
</xsl:if>
```